# Different ways of getting a string resource

Tags: android, string, resources

What is the difference between `getResources().getString(...)` and `getString()` when called from my activity? I read that `getText(...)` returns stylized text, but when should I use `getResources(`) as opposed to directly calling `getString()`?

Comment: I think `getText` is used for Assets... check the source

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same nothing special about them if you fetch the Android source code and specially the [Context Class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/content/Context.java#Context.getString%28int%29) for exemple

```
 public final String getString(int resId) {
     return getResources().getString(resId);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`getString()` is a convenient way since it is used regularly (you don't need to type `getResources()`…). Other than that, they're same.